# Return Msg to Caller when state_timeout occur in gen_statem erlang

Tags: erlang, timeout, message-passing, gen-server, reply

For example:
state looks like this:

```
state1({call,Caller},Msg,Data) ->
    NewData = do_somthing(),
    {next_State,state2,NewData,[{reply,Caller,NewMsg},{state_timeout,5000,any}]}.
```

timeout state:

```
state2(state_timeout,Msg,Data) ->
    something() ( Here my question)
```

I need to return a Message when timeout is occuer.
How can I do that if I dont know who is the Caller at state2(state_timeout,Msg,Data)?

Answer (score 0):

`Data` can be anything you want:

```
NewData = {do_something(), Caller},
```

then:

```
state2(state_timeout,Msg,{Data, Caller}) ->
```